# Binding buttons in StackLayout displays additional things

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I am trying find way to write and get items from my StackLayout in my ViewModel.
My implementation XAML:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="PlayerList" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"/>
```

And implementation for ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Button> Players { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Button>();
public GamePointViewModel()
{
    InitializePlayerList();
}

public void InitializePlayerList()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GameSettings.PlayerCount; i++)
    {
        Button newBtn = new Button();

        newBtn.Text = GameSettings.Players[i];
        newBtn.ClassId = i.ToString();
        newBtn.Clicked += ButtonEvent_Click;
        Players.Add(newBtn);
    }
}

void ButtonEvent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    if (button.Background == Brush.Green)
    {
        button.Background = Brush.Gray;
    }
    else
    {
        button.Background = Brush.Green;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I see some additional text in my interface:

[image]

But I expected only buttons. What I miss?

Comment: Your VM should not contain UI elements

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest, alternative approach.

Instead of binding visual elements (In your case buttons), you should be binding Models to your VisualElements (for example, ObservableCollection of Players to your CollectionView ItemSource).

And instead of adding event handlers to those VisualElements, you should be using Commands. (For example bound to TapGestureRecognizers of this CollectionView).

For changing the appearance of those buttons, you can use Data Triggers, Visual States, Styles, Control Templates, Value Convertors, or combination of them.
(For example Player.isActive becomes false, the color of the VisualElement becomes gray)

There is no point in using MVVM, just to bind UI to UI.